# Unable to access database or create table in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

A project I'm working on I have just combined two other projects. Both projects had separate databases and dbadapters. I kept them as is and joined both of them. For a while the app worked perfectly.

When I converted it to an apk and when I launched it on my mobile one of the table started not getting created. After that the same issue kept on occuring when I ran it in debugging mode in my android studio.

my first db helper

```
public class NotesDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null, date text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the note
     * @param body the body of the note
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createNote(String title, String body, String date) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to update
     * @param title value to set note title to
     * @param body value to set note body to
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body,String date) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

        //This lines is added for personal reason
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        //One more parameter is added for data
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

my second db helper

```
public class RemindersDbAdapter {

    //
    // Databsae Related Constants
    //
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


    private static final String TAG = "ReminderDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation SQL statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"; 



    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public RemindersDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public RemindersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new reminder using the title, body and reminder date time provided. 
     * If the reminder is  successfully created return the new rowId
     * for that reminder, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the reminder
     * @param body the body of the reminder
     * @param reminderDateTime the date and time the reminder should remind the user
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime); 

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the reminder with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all reminders in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all reminders
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the reminder that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching reminder, if found
     * @throws SQLException if reminder could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the reminder using the details provided. The reminder to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title, body and reminder date time
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to update
     * @param title value to set reminder title to
     * @param body value to set reminder body to
     * @param reminderDateTime value to set the reminder time. 
     * @return true if the reminder was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

and my logcat

```
375-375/com.example.note E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.note, PID: 375
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.note/com.example.note.ReminderListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: reminders (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, reminder_date_time FROM reminders
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: reminders (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, reminder_date_time FROM reminders
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
            at com.example.note.RemindersDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders(RemindersDbAdapter.java:141)
            at com.example.note.ReminderListActivity.fillData(ReminderListActivity.java:56)
            at com.example.note.ReminderListActivity.onCreate(ReminderListActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: I had the same problem... Just check your create tables SQL is very delicate so even a single "," can cause you trouble

Comment: at first itwas working perfectly while it in debugging  mode.the problem only came when i convert it in to apk.after that in debugging mode also same error continues.

Comment: Have you modified the table creation structure?

Comment: in fact i haven't touched the database section.i have done only some xml edits that's all

Answer (score 0):

Your table is not being created since you have got following logcat error

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: reminders (code 1):
```

You better study about sqlite database in following link and try to implement it
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: but i have wrote the code to create the two databases and they was perfectly once.Thats my doubt.if it was working once why its not working when it was converted to apk

Answer (score 0):

Try incrementing the database version because i think you might have modified the database structure.
Once you modify the `structure` of the table you need to increment the `database version`

Comment: i tried incrementing database version but still the error exists